# IllegalArgumentException: width and height must be > 0 - error when loading an image using Imgcodecs.imread

Tags: java, android, opencv, kotlin, mobile

I'm using `Imgcodecs.imread` to upload an image from the phone's gallery to perform a segmentation on this image. However, when creating a bitmap to display it on the screen, I was receiving the `error: IllegalArgumentException: width and height must be> 0.` I soon realized that `Imgcodecs.imread` is not opening the image correctly, because I used the log to see the outputs of variable. As below.

```
// Load the image
   val srcOriginal = Imgcodecs.imread(currentPhotoPath)
    val src: Mat = srcOriginal.clone()
    Log.i("teste", src.toString())
    Log.i("teste", srcOriginal.toString())
    Log.i("teste", src.rows().toString()+"\n"+ src.cols())
    // Create a blank image of zeros (same dimension as img)
    // It should be grayscale (1 color channel)
    val markers = Mat.zeros(srcOriginal.rows(), srcOriginal.cols(), CvType.CV_32F)

    // This step is manual. The goal is to find the points
    // which create the result we want. I suggest using a
    // tool to get the pixel coordinates.

    // Dictate the area of interest
    for(x in my_canvas.pointsToDrawX.indices) {
            markers.put(
                my_canvas.pointsToDrawX.get(x).toInt(),
                my_canvas.pointsToDrawY.get(x).toInt(),
                255.0
            )
    }

    val src1 = srcOriginal.clone()
    val bmpOut = Bitmap.createBitmap(src1.cols(), src1.rows(), Bitmap.Config.RGB_565)
    //Create Bitmap
    Utils.matToBitmap(src1, bmpOut)
    image.setImageBitmap(bmpOut)
```

Output Log:

[image]

Output error:

[image]

why is Imgcodecs.imread not opening the image correctly?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to add file read and write permissions. For that, you can use the libs: implementation `'com.tbruyelle.rxpermissions2: rxpermissions: 0.9.4@aar'` and implementation `"io.reactivex.rxjava2: rxandroid: 2.0.1"`. With this, when opening the image you will check if you have permission to write and read using the code below:

```
private fun tryOpenFile() {

    rxPermissions
        .request(Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE, Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE)
        .subscribe({ granted ->
            if (granted) {
                val getPictureIntent = Intent(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT).apply {
                    type = "image/*"}
                val pickPictureIntent = Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK, MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI)
                val chooserIntent = Intent.createChooser(getPictureIntent, "Select Image")
                    .apply { putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_INITIAL_INTENTS, arrayOf(pickPictureIntent)) }
                startActivityForResult(chooserIntent, PICK_IMAGE_INTENT)
            } else {
                Toast.makeText(this@MainActivity, "App needs permission to read/write external storage", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
            }
        })
        .addTo(disposables)

}
```

I hope it works.